# Apache will not start, no httpd error messages

Tags: apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux, httpd

I am trying to start the httpd service on RHEL 7.

When I run `systemctl start httpd`, it fails.

Here is the output of `journalctl -xe`.  There are no apparent error message for httpd, Would the errors for polkitd be affecting apache? How would I resolve these?

```
Jun 10 10:59:50 localhost.localdomain polkitd[850]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:4462:116143 (system bus name :1.57 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jun 10 10:59:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up. 
Jun 10 10:59:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 10 10:59:50 localhost.localdomain kill[4468]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jun 10 10:59:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 10 10:59:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jun 10 10:59:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jun 10 10:59:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Jun 10 10:59:50 localhost.localdomain polkitd[850]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:4462:116143 (system bus name :1.57, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

EDIT:  log output and additional info

Here is the output of `tail -f 10 /var/log/httpd/error_log`.  The log files are stored on an NFS mounted directory (hosted remotely).  I can edit the files from the machine running apache, but apache itself doesn't seem to be able to write to them.

```
==> /var/log/httpd/error_log <==
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /data/web/logs/new-error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /data/web/logs/new-error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /data/web/logs/new-error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /data/web/logs/new-error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /data/web/logs/io-new-error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

EDIT 2: Additional logs

```
[root@localhost web]# sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log
 78% donetype=AVC msg=audit(1465576122.933:606): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=4384 comm="httpd" name="logs" dev="0:38" ino=1060076 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0 tclass=dir

**** Invalid AVC allowed in current policy ***

type=AVC msg=audit(1465576695.541:615): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=4489 comm="httpd" name="sims" dev="0:38" ino=1060159 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file

**** Invalid AVC allowed in current policy ***

 78% donetype=AVC msg=audit(1465576695.580:616): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=4489 comm="httpd" name="sims" dev="0:38" ino=1060159 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file

**** Invalid AVC allowed in current policy ***

type=AVC msg=audit(1465576695.581:617): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=4489 comm="httpd" name="logs" dev="0:38" ino=1060076 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0 tclass=dir

**** Invalid AVC allowed in current policy ***

100% done
found 0 alerts in /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Comment: What changed did you made in `httpd.conf` ? Show me the output of `tail -f 10 /var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: I added the log output above.  It looks like there is a problem writing to the log files.  I haven't made any changes directly to httpd.conf

Answer (score 3):

If your RHEL 7 system has SELinux **enforcing**, you need to enable the SELinux boolean values to get NFS working. To check if your system is utilizing SELinux:

```
# getenforce
```

If the above returns **enforcing**, please continue:

```
# getsebool -a | grep httpd_use_nfs
```

If the above returns `httpd_use_nfs --> off`, run the following command to permanently allow Apache to use NFS.

```
# setsebool -P httpd_use_nfs on
```

Apache should be allowed to write to those error log files now.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey.  I've set `httpd_use_nfs` to `on`, but I'm still getting the error `Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file`.  Do the files need to have a particular permissions level or owner?

Comment: Let's confirm what user & group Apache is running as: `httpd -S | grep 'User\|Group'`. For example, let's say you get `User: name="apache"` and `Group: name="apache"`, then your NFS directory `/data/web/logs` should be mounted with user & group as `apache:apache`

Comment: The `user:group` is indeed `apache:apache`.  I chown'd the `/data/web/logs` directory to `apache:apache`, but I'm still getting the same errors.  do the actual log files needto be `apache:apache` too?

Comment: Yes, the logs should be owned by `apache:apache` too. You have two options- Option 1: Delete the logs (if they are useless) and restart apache; apache will re-create the logs automatically. Option 2: chown all logs to `apache:apache`

Comment: I tried Option 1 and Option 2 with no luck.  With Option 1 I got the same errors and it did not recreate the log files

Comment: Are the apache logs still the same? If so, could you see if SELinux is still giving you errors? `sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log`

Comment: I posted the output of the audit.log in the OP.  I tried to apply the fix from this issue: http://serverfault.com/a/677805, but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Let's try to separate the issue first. Can you try changing the default Apache logs back to `/var/log/httpd/{access_log/error_log}` and then restart Apache to see if `{access_log/error_log}` gets re-generated? If your logs get re-generated and Apache works, at least we can focus more on the NFS part.

Comment: I commented out the log and httpd starts fine

Answer (score 0):

Try `apachectl configtest` and you will see the error